# Pi Camera preview not showing and image not being captured on laptop

Tags: pi-3, raspicam

I just started working on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and have set it up on my laptop. I have connected it using an Ethernet port with a VNC Viewer. 
In my project I need to capture images during the stream of a video. I am using Raspberry Pi Camera for this. 
I opened the terminal and ran the command

```
raspistill -o image.jpg
```

However nothing happens. The light on my camera module lights up and after a point of time just goes off. In a video they mentioned a preview to appear on my screen but nothing came. The cursor just moved to the next line.

Many mentioned that you may require a monitor for this. I don't find any logic in this. I want to achieve the same task using my laptop. Please advise on the same.

I have enabled my camera interface and rebooted my VNC Server as well.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you'll get a preview over VNC. Worth a look over [the instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md) at any rate. You *definitely* won't get a preview with your current command, which just saves a file.

Comment: you could enable direct capture mode (instructions in the [docs](https://www.realvnc.com/docs/raspberry-pi.html))

Comment: Only the "realvnc" implementation currently supports forwarding the camera's preview over the VNC connection (because it's the only implementation that uses dispmanx for screen-scraping at the moment). You also have to enable "experimental capture mode" or something like that in the options interface